# Daily motion android SDK crashes while switching the video to full screen

Tags: android, webview, dailymotion-api

Integrated the below SDK for video playback

https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android

and there occurred an rare crash while the full screen button pressed.
Note: The crash is happening only in HTC M8 running on android 5.0.2, but the same content is playing fine in other devices running 5.0.2. The crash happens all time

Below is the error log coming while the crash happens

```
04-29 17:50:39.683  27210-27210/com.quickplay.hawk I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'HTMLVideoElement.webkitSupportsFullscreen' is deprecated. Its value is true if the video is loaded.", source:  (0)
04-29 17:50:39.683  27210-27210/com.quickplay.hawk I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'HTMLVideoElement.webkitEnterFullscreen()' is deprecated. Please use 'Element.requestFullscreen()' instead.", source:  (0)
04-29 17:50:39.773  27210-27210/com.quickplay.hawk W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
04-29 17:50:39.813  27210-27210/com.quickplay.hawk I/InputMethodManager﹕ [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.quickplay.hawk, inputType=0xa1, imeOptions=0x12000000, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=org.chromium.android_webview.FullScreenView{ec3294 VFED..C. .F...... 0,0-1794,1080}, mServedInputConnectionWrapper=android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper@e72d13d
04-29 17:50:39.813  27210-27317/com.quickplay.hawk E/Adreno-EGL﹕ <eglGetoglFunctionsByPtr:294>: Invalid client version
04-29 17:50:39.863  27210-27210/com.quickplay.hawk I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'HTMLVideoElement.webkitDisplayingFullscreen' is deprecated. Please use the 'fullscreenchange' event instead.", source:  (0)
04-29 17:50:40.003  27210-28905/com.quickplay.hawk W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (701, 0)
04-29 17:50:40.043  27210-27317/com.quickplay.hawk E/Adreno-EGL﹕ <eglGetoglFunctionsByPtr:294>: Invalid client version
04-29 17:50:40.043  27210-28665/com.quickplay.hawk E/Adreno-EGL﹕ <eglGetoglFunctionsByPtr:294>: Invalid client version
04-29 17:50:40.053  27210-28665/com.quickplay.hawk W/Adreno-GSL﹕ <gsl_ldd_control:416>: ioctl fd 61 code 0xc02c093d (IOCTL_KGSL_SUBMIT_COMMANDS) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
04-29 17:50:40.053  27210-28665/com.quickplay.hawk W/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglWaitSyncKHR:5854>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-29 17:50:40.053  27210-28665/com.quickplay.hawk E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_fence_egl.cc(63)] Failed to wait for EGLSync. error:EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-29 17:50:40.053  27210-28665/com.quickplay.hawk A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:gl_fence_egl.cc(65)] Check failed: g_ignore_egl_sync_failures.
04-29 17:50:40.933  27210-28906/com.quickplay.hawk W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)
```

Comment: Did you try on the mobile website ? Does it work there ?

Comment: I am trying to playback a video inside the dailymotion sdk which is integrated into an app.

Comment: yes, what I try to understand is if this bug is a bug with the dailymotion SDK or with the platform HTML5 integration itself, that kind of things could happen.

Comment: Is there any workaround to fix the same

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by an error in Google WebView version 42.0.2311.137 on Android 5.0 with devices running the Adreno 3xx GPU. Which unfortunately is a lot of devices including some Nexus devices, S4, S5, HTC m7/m8 etc.

This has been fixed in version 42.0.2311.138, but Google has not rolled that out to end-users yet.

All we can do at this point is to wait for Google to push out their fix via Google Play.

More information:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482298